# hyperlink section google sheet download pdf

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, download

I have a google sheet document with a link to another sheet (of the same sheet). I do that with action scritp and it works.
The problem is when I want to download the sheet with the link as a PDF file. When I have that file downloaded, the link doesn't work. The pdf file says that is unable to open it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have to use PDF .. I don't understand why it doen't work when I have downloaded the sheet. If I link an external page (www.google.es), that works but not an internal link of the page

Comment: function enllac()
{

  var llibre        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var full          = llibre.getSheetByName("Full 2"); 

  var prefixenllas      = "=HYPERLINK(\"#gid=";

  // posem els enllaços corresponens a l'Índex del llibre i a l'Índex de la PGA - Memòria
  var enllas   = prefixenllas+full.getSheetId()+"\";\""+full.getName()+"\")";

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(enllas);
  llibre.getSheetByName("Full 3").getRange("A1").setValue(enllas); 
}